# How can I update Material UI theme dynamically via Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, themes, material-ui

I have the following React component that uses a custom Material UI theme

const getTheme = name => themes.filter(theme => theme.name === name)[0] || themes[0];

```
const Root = props => (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(getTheme(props.theme).data)}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route component={AppContainer}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

It's fed by a container

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    theme: state.settings.theme
});

const RootContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Root);
```

When I update the theme name on a settings page the state is updated (confirmed via Redux logging), but the theme isn't updated. However, when I navigate away from the page, the new theme is applied.

Presumably the change in state isn't causing the `Root` component to re-render, or there's something I don't understand in the way this is applied

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(getTheme(props.theme).data)}>
```

Any idea how I can get the theme to update the instance it's changed in the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to also pass the updated theme as a prop to my App component (just below Root in the hierarchy). Seems like it's to do with the fact that the theme is passed via the context and changing a prop in the component that configures the theme wasn't enough to trigger the required updates.

Comment: I'm having the same issue described in the original question. I tried something like this solution (forcing the root component to re-render on theme change), but it only updated the theme for components directly below the root component, not those deeper down the hierarchy. Do you mind sharing your solution in more detail ?
At this point, I'm not sure whether this is an issue with the react context API, material-ui or my own application.

Comment: @dommer This answer doesn't actually show what you accomplished. Can you post an example?

Comment: For anyone googling years later (like me), I managed to solve this by putting `createMuiTheme` in the component, rather than in my theme file. In other words, changing <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> (where theme was already created) to <ThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(theme)}>.

Comment: createMuiTheme(theme) inside theme provide and it's not doing anything. Using mui v5, still open quesiton how to reload theme :\ will try to dig more into it

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this. While theme is provided to ReactJs threw ReactJs Context API it, check Caveats section of ReactJs docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats So we exactly need to create new object to re-render the context for consumers.

[image]

So, what i did is this:

1. I created custom hook to get if mode should be light or dark:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useGetThemeMode() {
  const initialMode =
    window.matchMedia &&
    window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches === true
      ? "dark"
      : "light";

  const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = useState(initialMode);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const newMode =
        window.matchMedia &&
        window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches === true
          ? "dark"
          : "light";
      if (themeMode !== newMode) {
        setThemeMode(newMode);
      }
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [themeMode]);

  return themeMode;
}
```

And then in Root component i provide this theme object to ThemeProvider:

```js
  const themeMode = useGetThemeMode();
  const theme = createTheme(getCustomThemeStyles());
  theme.palette.mode = themeMode; // <---- The key line
```